# Python-Firebase Errors/ Changing Thonny Interpreter

Tags: firebase, python-3.6, thonny

Trying to make a simple system where once numbers are inputted by a user they are sent to Firebase. When doing this however, I am left with a syntax error which probably stems from the current version of python thonny is using not being compatable with the python-firebase plugin. Is there any Python to Firebase Plugins that work with the current version of python? If not, is there any way to switch thonny's interpreter to an older version? Anything ive found online seems to have been published before a UI update as there is no longer an option to use an alternative interpreter

[Thonny interpreter options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCMRV.png)[My current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SllGx.png)[Error im receving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FShIC.png)

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.